# Properties file path was not found! (Relevant only for builds running on a CI Server)

Tags: gradle, artifactory

I get the following message from gradle when I run a 'gradle build' with Artifactory configured.

```
[buildinfo] Properties file path was not found! (Relevant only for builds running on a CI Server)
```

It starts appearing when I include the following line in my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'
```

I would like to know what it exactly means and what to do about it, but I cannot find anything anywhere about it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Gradle integration with Artifactory can be achieved by using the Gradle Artifactory Plugin or alternatively from a CI server (Jenkims, Bamboo or TeamCity), by using the relevant Artifactory Plugin for the CI server.

All Artifactory Plugins for the CI servers share the same code with the Gradle Artifactory Plugin to integrate with Artifactory.

The warning message you're getting is relevant only in case the build is running on a CI server. If it is not, this message is not an indication of a problem and it should be ignored. To avoid confusion, in the next release this message type will be changed to info instead of warning.

As for the actual meaning of this message, here's a short description:

> The Artifactory Plugins for CI servers use a property file to pass
>   information to the build tool process (Gradle for example). The Gradle
>   Artifactory Plugin code (running as part of the Gradle process) uses
>   the data of in the file for artifact resolution and deployment from/to
>   Artifactory, as well as deployment for the build information to
>   Artifactory.

Using the Gradle Artifactory Plugin directly from your build script does not use or require this properties file and that's why you're seeing this message.

Comment: @eyal-ben-moshe do you have a hint on how to setup the properties for a ci build?